Text books or articles for "Nonlocal Analysis and Geometric Measure Theory" and "Non-smooth Analysis and Geometry"
I'm interested in the topics in

Nonlocal Analysis and Geometric Measure Theory

Non-smooth Analysis and Geometry


I want to know if there are some textbook or "key" articles for each of the subject, especially related to the development in the past 20 years or so. I'm interested to start with even the construction of the distance, metric in 1. and the some basic definitions such the derivative(integration) that was used in 2., from an introductory level.
Could you provide some references, please? I'm not sure where exactly to start.
